# node AJV validation schema

Tags: node.js, jsonschema, json-schema-validator, ajv

Using version 6.5

My issue is I have a request object that must contain one attribute and should contain one and only one other attribute from a list of attributes OR None of those specified attributes. I have done some digging around and have been unable to find a solution for this issue.

Possible valid requests:

```
{ 'query': {...}, 'limit': 1 }
{ 'query': {...}, 'count': true }
{ 'query': {...}, 'max': 'my_string' }
```

An invalid request would be:

```
{ 'query': {...}, 'limit': 1, 'count': true }
```

or

```
{ 'query': {...}, 'max': 'my_string', limit: 1 }
```

etc.

The best ajv validator object I have come up with is the following:

```
{
    "type": "object",
    "required": ["query"],
    "maxProperties": 2,
    "properties": {
        "query": {
            "type": "object"
        },
        "limit": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "count": {
            "type": "boolean"
        },
                "max": {
                        "type": "string"
                }
    }
}
```

But I know this won't scale as our application grows. I was wondering if there was a way to specify that the object requires "query" and ONE or NONE of "limit", "count", "max.

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to accomplish what I am looking for. This can be done using the "dependency" validator:

```
"dependencies": {
    "limit": { "properties": 
        { 
            "count": { "not": {} },
            "max": { "not": {} }
        }
    },
    "count": { "properties": 
        { 
            "limit": { "not": {} },
            "max": { "not": {} }
        }
    },
    "max": { "properties": 
        { 
            "limit": { "not": {} },
            "count": { "not": {} }
        }
    }
}
```

If anyone knows a better way I would love to know!